# Google Map Pins Missing

Tags: google-maps

I have a [site](http://mychinaroots.com) using Google map but is now having pins disappear. The code that create the pins are valid and have already been tested. From the inspector, they all seem to be pointing to the a.xa.Fa property in http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/13/9/main.js which I believe is injected (as I have included no such script).
  I'm quite desperate and have no idea what to do with it. So any input is appreciated.

Comment: I'm open yous site and get this http://gyazo.com/8ca5b779dc4388bcb8a4d1a885da93d1. But in Chrome console I'm get this error `Cannot read property 'Fa' of undefined main.js:27` and in FF - this error `TypeError: a.Xa is undefined`

Comment: @joni_jones: exactly the problem. Now how do I solve it is the question

Comment: Please, add your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to add markers without supplying a proper pin-argument to `add()`, therefore the creation of `new google.maps.MarkerImage(pin)` will fail in `add()`.

This happens the first time at the 6th marker(that's why you see only 5 markers, the error will stop the script-execution at this point).

Solution: you may either fix it(supply a proper pin-argument), there is also a LatLng of 0,0 provided, I guess something went wrong with your data.

or add this to the begin of `add()` to have a default-pin for these situations:

```
pin=pin||'http://www.mychinaroots.com/wp-content/themes/mychinaroots/images/8-default.png';
```